# What are the diferences between these field declarations

Tags: lua, moonscript

In MoonScript, what is the difference between these types field declarations?:

```
class SomeClass
     a : {}
    @b : {}
     c = {}
    @d = {}
```

Answer (score 0):

`a: {}` creates `a` in the base class and is available per instance.
https://moonscript.org/reference/#the-language/table-literals

If the value is a table, `a: {}` will create it only once. To actually have unique tables, you will need to create it in the constructor (and thus set it in the instance): https://moonscript.org/reference/#the-language/object-oriented-programming

`@b: {}` creates `b` in the class object and is "shared".
https://moonscript.org/reference/#the-language/object-oriented-programming/class-variables

`c = {}` is a class declaration statement, it is a local variable available during class declaration. With `self` you have access to the class.

`@d = {}` is a class declaration statement, but due to the `@` prefix it's stored in the class.
https://moonscript.org/reference/#the-language/object-oriented-programming/class-declaration-statements

Paste your code in https://moonscript.org/compiler/ to see all this in action.

Comment: `a: {}` seems to be shared amongst the instances; not per instance. In fact, they all seem to be. Seems like the only way to create instance vars is within fat arrow functions, by using @varname

Comment: True, you will have to overwrite the property once to avoid using the base class value, similar as in https://moonscript.org/reference/#the-language/object-oriented-programming  I fixed the answer. I have to admit, I never used moonscript and I may miss more convenient ways to do that.

Comment: I also didn't find an actual difference between `@a:` and `@a=`, since the compiler doesn't complain when re declaring a property anyways. It compiles to the same code.